# Issue connecting to elastic search from a maven project

Tags: spring, maven, elasticsearch, guava

Inside my maven-Spring project, I am trying to connect to ElasticSearch as:
 TransportClient esclient = TransportClient.builder().build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

I added maven dependency - org.elasticsearch 2.4.5

I keep getting :
 **Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.(ThreadPool.java:192)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:133)**
    at com.controller.AppController.loginPage(AppController.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)

To get rid of this exception:
I tried adding Guava 18.0 Dependency, Adding exclusion in org.elasticSearch and shaded guava for maven as well.

Without adding guava dependency or exclusion, this is my dependency:tree

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:tree (default-cli) ---
com.spring.mvc:App:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
+- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
|  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
|  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
|  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
|  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
|  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
+- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
+- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.31:compile
+- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
|  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.20:compile
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
+- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
+- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
\- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:2.4.5:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.4:compile
   |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:5.5.4:compile
   |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:5.5.4:compile
   |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:5.5.4:compile
   +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:5.5.4:compile
   |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:5.5.4:compile
   |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.5:compile
   +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
   +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.0:compile
   +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
   +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.5:compile
   +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.1:compile
   +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.8.1:compile
   +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.1:compile
   +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.1:compile
   +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
   +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final:compile
   +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.2:compile
   +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
   +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.6:compile
   +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3.1:compile
   \- com.twitter:jsr166e:jar:1.1.0:compile
```

Comment: Well, I don't what *you* miss, but what *we* miss is clearly more information! What exception are you getting, you probably only linked the message, not the exception itself. So edit your question, add all information you have, all your maven configuration and tell us exactly what happens.

Comment: Hi Olivier, I updated my comment with the required info.

Comment: You have a dependency conflict on Guava. The method [`MoreExecutors.directExecutor()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html) was added in Guava 18. So you probably have a Guava with a version less than 18 on the classpath when you execute your application. On the classpath means: in your maven configuration (directly or indirectly) so make a `mvn dependency:tree` to find out if there are more instances of Guava in your maven configuration. If not, check the classpath of your application runner (Glassfish in this case).

Comment: Hi Olivier, I updated the question with dependency:tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On looking more, I found GlassFish's own dependencies leak into apps classpath (and GF uses an older Guava) So the fix for Glassfish4.1 user's will be to update guava.jar in /glassfish/modules with guava 19 version.

Use this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Since fixing the issue requires meddling with GF's own libraries and is error-prone, I moved to Tomcat and it's working fine with no other changes.